# init git on deployment server for nodejs

Tags: linux, git, node.js, ubuntu

I want to create a deployment server with nodejs application. I'll write nodejs code on my windows machine and push it on that ubuntu linux server. Can you tell how should I setup git for pushing a new code into this one?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to setup git on server is to create empty bare git repository on server:

```
mkdir -p path/to/git/repos/myproject.git
cd path/to/git/repos/myproject.git
git init --bare
```

Now, go back to Windows box and setup [msysgit git command line](http://msysgit.github.com/) client or [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit) to connect to your Linux box over ssh.

Your goal is to successfully clone your empty repo from the server:

```
git clone ssh://username@server:/path/to/git/repos/myproject.git
```

Once this is done, you can `git add` your content to directory `myproject`, then `git commit` it and finally `git push`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a more detailed tutorial about this?